# How to get all files and folders on a SharePoint site, using office 365 REST API for python?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, python

I want to automate downloading all the documents in multiple SharePoint sites with python, so I want a way to get all folders and files in a "Shared Documents" library in SharePoint sites.

Alternatively I would like to know a way to iterate over all of them so I can read all the files (without downloading).